# Accessibility of a element. Role=tablist

Tags: html, angular

Good morning guys, I'm checking the accessibility of my site and I have a doubt regarding an element.
On my site I have a switch that allows me to change the display of some data, this data can be displayed as a table or in card format.
The switch is made up of two buttons, inside each of the two buttons there is the role="tab" attribute.
Both buttons are contained within a div.

What I'm wondering is: is it necessary for the role="tablist" attribute to be present inside the div element?
I didn't put it and it is reported to me as an error by an automatic analysis tool.

I also noticed that the screen reader slightly changes the reading of the element based on the presence or absence of the role="tablist" attribute, in my opinion it is better without it (When it is present an extra word is read: "page ").
Here is a small snippet of the code:

```
<div _ngcontent-rtx-c0="" class="...">
  <button _ngcontent-rtx-c0="" mat-stroked-button="" role="tab" class="..." aria-label="Table view" aria-selected="true">
  </button>
  <button _ngcontent-rtx-c0="" mat-stroked-button="" role="tab" class="..." aria-label="Card view" aria-selected="false">
  </button>
</div>
```